# How can I close my Open Source project and what is required from me in order to make it closed source?

Tags: licensing, open-source, legal, closed-source

Let's say I wanted to close my "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" licensed project, to which I'm the only contributor, and make it closed source.

- Do I still need to make the existing "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" licensed code available after closing the project or can I refuse giving out the source code for old revisions that was previously "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" licensed?
- Can I theoretically keep the the code "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" licensed even after removing the public source code or do I have to distribute the source code if I'm using a "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" license?

Comment: are you asking from perspective of one who currently maintains said project? because I can hardly imagine how it would be possible to "close" it against maintainer will

Comment: I am not sure you can close a GPLv2 project. Someone could have downloaded it, improved it, and distribute his improved version as GPLv2.

Comment: Have you accepted contributions from anyone else to the project? If so, did they give you ownership of their contributions? You can only decide on future licensing of *code you yourself own*.

Comment: you can release the same project under different licenses (for example a free personal use and a paid commercial) that inlcudes a open source licence and a closed source license

Comment: More detail on why you [can't branch a closed source project from gpl code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_license)

Comment: What is the use case? I am not against, just curious.

Comment: Sorry for not making this clear: I'm asking this question from the view of the author and maintainer of the Open Source project.

Comment: The author? or the *sole* copyright holder?  Those are two different things.

Comment: To keep thing simple, let's say I'm the only contributer to this project.

Comment: @ErikR.Yverling - If you do take a GPL project private, realize that there will be some amount of backlash from any community you've got around the project. People tend to get seriously worked up when this kind of thing happens.

Comment: Is your project using (linking against) other gpl-libraries ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two cases in which it is possible to effectively change the copyright license on existing code.

1. The existing copyright license gives you the right to change the license or to sub-license the code. The GPL licenses **do not** fall in this category of licenses.
2. You are one of the copyright holders on the code and **all** copyright holders explicitly agree to the license change. If you ever accepted contributions from others without an explicit re-assignment of the copyright, then you the copyright on those contributions belongs to the person that wrote the contribution and you are bound by the license terms that were in effect when the contribution was made.
   If you want to change the license, you must get permission from **all** contributers. If any one of them refuses permission, then you must either remove their contributions entirely or forget about the license change.

In both cases, the license change only applies to *future* versions.

If you don't fall in any of the two categories above, then you **can not** change the license.

---

There is one additional possibility to keep your code secret:
Copyright licenses govern what *others* can do with code *you* own. They are only relevant when you distribute the code (either in binary or source code form). If you don't distribute your own code, you don't need to bother to think about copyright licenses and if you use code owned by others but you don't redistribute it, then you only need to pay attention to the right to modify or make derived works. In all open-source licenses, any requirements on providing the source code is tied to distribution of your changes and don't apply if you don't distribute.

The key here thus is distribution of the program/library. Different licenses have different notions of what constitutes distribution, ranging from giving out copies to allowing remote access to the program.

But in all cases, if an organization makes tools for internal use, then allowing employees to use those tools is not considered distribution under copyright law. This means that you don't need to release the code for internal tools, even if those tools make use of GPL-licensed code.

Comment: I'd restrict the last paragraph to GPL, not open source in general. The conditions vary between licenses, for example AGPL requires you to provide the source code, even if you run it as a publicly accessible server without distribution the binary code.

Comment: The AGPL is the odd one out here, because it (re-)defines distribution to include accessing the program remotely.

Comment: Thank you for a valuable answer. Could you just clarify if I still need to distribute the source code for old versions of the project, even if I'm legally able to change the license to "closed source".

Comment: @ErikR.Yverling: You are not required to remain supporting/providing old versions, but you also can't forbid others from keeping the old versions available.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Ah great. Finally should I interpret "...As long as you don't distribute the program/library, the requirements of an open-source license that you must provide the source code don't apply" as I'm in fact able to license code that are not publicly available as "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" as long as I don't distribute any executables or similar? What if I closed down my previously "GPL v 2.0 (or similar)" licensed project and removed all distributions, could I still keep the license even if it's not publicly available anymore?

Comment: @ErikR.Yverling: If the code is not already publicly available, you probably don't have the right to distribute it under any license. And you can't publish closed source software under the GPL. See also my edit.

Comment: @ErikR.Yverling - If you distributed the binaries at any point, then you have an obligation to provide source code to anyone you distributed the binaries to for some period of time (see the actual text of the GPL for details). You do NOT have an obligation to distribute the source beyond the people you distributed the binaries to.

Comment: I am not entirely sure that allowing employees to use internal software is never a distribution. This is the case indeed for SME with one geographical location. It might not be the case for multinational corporations with geographically different business units & profit centers (sometimes, one unit in one country is *selling* some "internal" software or service to another unit in another country, and that might become a distribution).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Even then, at worst you must provide the source code to those business units that you provided with the software. You are never required to provide source code to the general public unless you already provide the binaries to the general public.

Comment: I think it should be noted that even if version 1.0 and 2.0 have been released under GPL you can still (as long as all copyright holders agree) at a later day release these versions under a non open source license as well. You cannot undo that 1.0 and 2.0 exists as GPL licensed. GPL does not prevent dual license and do not prevent retrospective dual license. It prevents users from losing rights achieved by distribution under GPL.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good, long, accepted answer already. This is a short answer.

Yes, as the sole copyright owner you can change the licence for all future distributions. You cannot change history.

Yes, if you have ever distributed binaries without source code under GPL then the obligation to provide source code of that version to those who relied on it is permanent. It never goes away.

What happens in the future depends absolutely on what licence you choose for any future distributions and (for you alone) is not affected by what you did in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a legal question and I am not a lawyer. But from what I understand about contracts and software licenses in general:

(1) If you release software under an open-source license, then unless that license says that you have the right to revoke it -- in which case I don't think it would qualify as "open source" by definition -- then you cannot revoke the old license. You could certainly decide to stop providing new versions under open source. So you could take the open source product, use it as the basis for a new project, and then continue development of the new project as copyrighted software. But the portions that were released under open source would still be open source.

As I say, I'm not a lawyer, but I say this based on common understanding of contracts. If I sell you my used car for $2000, I can't come back a year later and say that I've changed my mind and I want another $1000 for it. We made a deal, a contract, and once it's agreed to I can't unilaterally change the terms. But just because I sold you a used car for $2000 doesn't mean that I am obligated to charge exactly $2000 for every future used car I might want to sell.

(2) Just because you released an open source project does not mean that you are obligated to continue to make the source available forever. There are lots of projects that have been started but then discontinued because the project became obsolete, the developer lost interest, the web site where it was being distributed went out of business, etc. Anyone who already has a copy could re-distribute it himself. Just like, if I give $20 to the Salvation Army today, I am under no obligation to give to them again next year. But I can't take back the money I gave them last year.

Answer (score 0):

Only the copyright holder or copyright holder can ever sue you for license violations. So if all the copyright holders agree, they can do whatever they want with their license, and nobody can do anything about it. If someone else is the copyright holder, you have to agree with their license.

Now if I received a copy of your software with for example GPL license, any license changes that you make don't retroactively change my license. I still have the right to use my copy of the software according to the license. I may have problems: If I don't have the source code, and you refuse to give it to me, then I cannot distribute the software, because I'm incapable of fulfilling the terms of the GPL license.

If someone received a copy of your software with GPL license *and* source code, and they are willing to share, then you can in practice not turn this into closed source, other than by convincing everyone in possession of the source code to delete their code.